# How can we find A using finite difference method?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$ L(u)=u_{xx}+u_{yy}\quad 0<x,y<1$$
with homogenous boundary conditions.

I have tried finite difference method,
$$ u_{xx}=\frac{u_{i-1,j}-2u{i,j}+u_{i+1,j}}{h^2}$$
$$ u_{yy}=\frac{u_{i,j-1}-2u{i,j}+u_{i,j+1}}{h^2}$$
Substituting in our equation, we have
$$ (u_{i-1,j}-2u{i,j}+u_{i+1,j})+(u_{i,j-1}-2u{i,j}+u_{i,j+1})=0$$
after I arranged it and used BC, I got the matrix A.
the steps are provided in link below in more details.
https://www.physik.uzh.ch/local/teaching/SPI301/LV-2013-Help/lvanlsconcepts.chm/lvac_finite_difference_method_for_laplace_eq.html

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use descriptive titles. Your title doesn't give any idea about the subject of the question, it's useless.

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest a title? because I do not know which method they used to get the matrix A.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the $-100$ is a misprint in $L$. Try replacing it with a $+$ sign.
And make the title of the question something to do with finite differences.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works without -100.